# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unexpected throwable caught java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11)

Tags: java, db2

I am using below statement for database in tomcat context.xml. Some time it works fine mainly when I restart my machine...but many time it give me Connection pool error

```
<Resource name="jdbc/nits" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="@xxxxx" password="xxxxx" driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
               url="jdbc:db2:DB0" defaultAutoCommit="false"/>
```

> Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: Unexpected throwable caught
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   11    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.uw.UWConnection.a(UWConnection.java:484)     at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.uw.UWConnection.(UWConnection.java:248)     at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:236)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1247)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1221)
>     ... 80 more

I tried the complete URL as well in statement after that it say Security Mechanism not supported. I am using DB2Jcc.jar. Please help me resolving this issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue. There was some conflict with old db2Jcc driver. This is a known issue in old drivers. I removed old one and now working fine form me with new one.